# Find minimum value of the trigonometrical expression

Tags: trigonometry

If $A+B+C=\pi$

then find the minimum value of

$\sin 3A+\sin 3B+\sin 3C$

where $0\le A\le \pi,0\le B \le \pi,0\le C\le \pi$

Comment: Use Lagange's multipliers method + eventual boundary cases.

Comment: http://exxamm.com/QuestionBank/practice/2211556420

Comment: can we have some other solution than the mentioned ??

Comment: @labbhattacharjee why ar eu referring to external paid site?

Comment: @maveric, check the timestamp of my post. I don't think it was paid at that time.

Comment: yeah yeah… sorry. but then can we have the soln other than posted here…

Answer (score 1):

The minimum value is $-2$.

Let be $A\leq B\leq C$. So we have $3A\leq \pi$ and so $\sin(3A)\geq 0$. So we get the minimum for $A=0, B=C=\frac{\pi}{2}$.